# htmlwidgets::saveWidget produces html file with default style="padding: 40px"

Tags: css, r, padding, htmlwidgets, htmltools

By default, the html document created by the `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` which use htmltools (for example, `htmlwidgets::saveWidget (reactable(iris))`) has the following attributes in the body tag: `<body class="vsc-initialized" style='margin: 9px; padding: 40px; ">` that leads to excessive padding from the top of the page.

I have tried to find any documentation how to change the `"style='padding: 40px;'"` but there is no documentation, and in the code of the [save_html function](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/blob/main/R/html_print.R) no styles are defined.

Please could you suggest how it is possible to change the style of the body tag and adjust the "padding: 40px" to the desired level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction to the solution has been provided by [cpsievert](https://github.com/cpsievert) in [this thread](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/297)

The final solution is the following:

```
object2save <- reactable(iris)
object2save$sizingPolicy$padding <- 4
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(object2save, file = "example.html", 
            selfcontained = FALSE, libdir = "lib")
```

Answer (score 1):

`style=""` should be double quotes. You have a single quote and a double.

```
<body class="vsc-initialized" style="margin: 9px; padding: 40px;">
```

You can try overwriting with `!important`

```
.vsc-initialized{padding: 0px!important;}
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot for your suggestion! It will work, but this CSS-based approach means I need to define the style manually each time. I would like to find a solution that alows to define padding during the execution of htmlwidgets::saveWidget.